# Enable Radeon HD 3000 on MSI 760GM-P23

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce, integrated-graphics

I have a MSI 760GM-P23 motherboard with an integrated Radeon HD 3000. I have a GeForce GTX 550 Ti installed as well. I am wanting to use the GeForce for GPGPU but I cannot get the Radeon enabled. Has anyone else faced this problem? I have the latest driver installed for the motherboard (H.B).